# Spring Boot - Enable JPA auditing only for one of two data sources

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two data sources (MySQL and Elasticsearch) configured in a Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE project and JpaAuditing enabled:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.companies.repository")
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("com.example.companies.repository.search")
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
}
```

And I have an entity which I store in both data sources:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@Document(indexName = "company")
public class Company extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

In Elasticsearch I need to have an exact copy of the entity in MySQL (including having the same `createdDate` and `lastModifiedDate`):

```
public Company save(Company company) {
    // MySql repository
    Company result = companyRepository.save(company);
    // Elasticsearch repository
    companySearchRepository.save(result);
    return result;
}
```

On create, the entity has the same details in both repositories, but on update, `lastModifiedDate` receives a different value in the second repository.

Is there an easy way to enable auditing only for one of the two data sources?

Thank you.